# Read only one RGB color in Octave

Tags: optimization, image-processing, octave

I have to read a few hundred RGB images using the PNG format. I only need one of the colors ( either Red, Green or Blue ), and right now I'm doing something like this:

```
A = imread(file);
A = A(:, :, 1);
```

I was wondering if it was possible to only read the values for one color, to make the reading faster. I need this operation to be as fast as possible.

Comment: It is not possible to read only one color but Octave allows for the syntax `A = imread (file)(;,:,1);` that saves you an extra line and a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like @carandraug mentioned, octave does not provide such a method. You already posted the simplest option. Octave is using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) as a back-end for reading image files. There is not much space for optimization here.

Besides, if you really need to speed up the reading process for a rather large quantity of images, you might want to look for alternative reading methods or implement your own. A good place to start is the source code of [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/). Another idea is to convert your RGB png's into uncompressed simple bmp's first. Let the process of converting the images handle by another fast program of your choice. Create the bmp's e.g. inside a ram drive and read them from octave with low-level commands (fread). Such strategies can be optimized to some degree. But they are only worth the effort if we are talking about a lot of images.